# Why my Galaxy Nexus is not detected by Eclipse in my android project?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have Galaxy Nexus Android version : 4.2.1
I downloaded this project: Color Histograms from here:

```
http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/index.html
```

When i connect my device to my pc i hear and see that it was connected and i can browse the files in my device no problems.

Connected as Media device (MTP)

But when i click on the eclipse menu Run > Run As > (none applicable) 
So i did Run > Run > No compatible targets were found...I select NO then a new window pop up:

Android Device Chooser

Choose a running Android device but it's empty.
Why it's not detecting my device ?

Comment: Do you checked USB Debugging Mode?

Comment: you might also need to find adb drivers for your device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable Developer Settings inside the settings

Enabling then on android 4.2 and higher is different.
I'm using a dutch device so bare in mind bad menu-translations.

Go to *Settings* -> *About this phone*.
Then tab multiple times on *Build-version* (about 7 or 8 times, if I remember correctly)
Then  you unlock the *Developer Settings*.
Go inside them and tick the *USB-Debugging* option -> *reconnect device*.

Hope this helps

EDIT: restarting the ADB service might help also: use `adb kill-server` to stop the server and `adb start-server` to start it again

Comment: This is the full answer. I had to tap it 7-8 times to be a developer ( in my case it's a PRO !!! ) and then selected the usb and it's working.

Answer (score 2):

go to Settings - Developer options and enable USB debugging.
if it's already checked, rebooting the device might help (i had this bug a few times)

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled USB Debugging ?
**To enable Nexus  USB Debugging Mode**

```
Go to Settings.
Select Developer options.
Turn on it.
Select OK to allow development settings.
Then tick USB debugging ~ Debug mode when USB is connected.
Select OK to allow USB debugging.
That’s all.
```

> If on version > 4.2 then do as **Blundell** says(in the answers below)

You might need to install drivers as well depending on the operating system

Comment: I have Eclipse SDK 3.7.2 and i couldn't find anywhere Settings and not Developer. Where is it ?

Comment: I meant in your nexus device and then reconnect

Comment: @varun Way to copy an paste my answer into yours, teach me your wise android skills. p.s. there is no 'if' he states he is on 4.2 in the Question

Comment: Oops i was looking for Settings in Eclipse. Anyway it's working now. Sorry.

Comment: @Varun ;-) credit where credit's due is the backbone of the internet right

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 4.2, developer options is hidden.

To enable the developer options, go to Settings > About > then find your Build Number ("JOP40C") and tap it 7 times.

This will enable developer options. Then go what sergio said

goto Settings > Developer Options > Enable USB Debugging

Refs:

- My Brain
- http://www.xda-developers.com/android/enable-developer-options-in-android-4-2-jelly-bean/
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1989777

Answer (score 0):

Hold your phone & once your mobile is connect. An alert is given to you, open it you will find a button that take your permission to access. press **Connect USB Storage** button To connect.

To assure the connection: Go to your Computer folder & you will be able to see your mobile as a removable disk.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable USB Debugging on you device
2. If it's a Samsung device, install SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones then restart your dev environment
3. Plug it in, try the debugger.
4. Watch our for an alert on your device. You need to give your PC permission.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above, nothing worked. Then I noticed, I had never seen that confirmation dialogue "Do you want to allow this computer access etc." that was supposed to come up on first connect.

So I decided to do **Settings > Developer options > Revoke USB debugging authorizations**. After restarting and reconnecting everything, I got the dialogue and now the phone is recognized.

(Done on Android 4.3 )